# Replay animations when scrolling back up (WordPress Avada Theme)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, animation

I have some css animations on my WordPress Avada page, and I want to replay them everytime I scroll back up.

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Can you provide what you tried so far? And which animations? CSS3 animations? jQuery animations? Native JS animations?

Comment: Please go read [ask].